# App has stopped - ProgressBar in Android

Tags: java, android

friends. I started to learn Android app developinng with Android Studio and Java. Now i am trying to make one progressbar. When app is started we have two EditText fields where first is 100 by default(how will be the max value for progressbar ) and one EditText field for increment by(this is step) for progressbar. When we click Start it must show up via dialog.

I write the code, there is no more errors, but app is closing when i hit the Start Button. The progressbar is not working

This is the code:
activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_max"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Max Value" />
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/maximum"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="100.0" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_increment"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Increment by"/>
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/increment"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="5.0" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/butt_Start"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Start" />
</LinearLayout>
```

This is the MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    int increment;
    ProgressDialog dialog;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button startButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.butt_Start);
        startButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(View view)
            {
                EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(increment);
                increment = Integer.parseInt(et.getText().toString());
                dialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
                dialog.setCancelable(true);
                dialog.setMessage("Loading...");
                dialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
                dialog.setProgress(0);
                EditText max = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.maximum);
                int maximum = Integer.parseInt(max.getText().toString());
                dialog.setMax(maximum);
                dialog.show();
                Thread background = new Thread(new Runnable()
                {
                    public void run()
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            while (dialog.getProgress() <= dialog.getMax())
                            {
                                Thread.sleep(500);
                                progressHandler.sendMessage(progressHandler.obtainMessage());
                            }
                        } catch (java.lang.InterruptedException e)
                        {

                        }
                    }
                });
                background.start();
            }

                Handler progressHandler = new Handler() {
                    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                        dialog.incrementProgressBy(increment);
                    }
                };

        });
        }
 }
```

Comment: add the stacktrace (in Android Monitor window of Android Studio)

Comment: Show the error log

Comment: From logcat i have this: 
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.app.ProgressDialog.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference

Answer (score 0):

There are some error with that code.. I will comment each by reporting your snippet:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    int increment;
    ProgressDialog dialog;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button startButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.butt_Start);
        startButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(View view)
            {
                EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(increment);
```

Here is the first error: not really a wrong thing, but it's better to istantiate the `EditText` in your `onCreate` (outside the `onClick`), because this way you will re-create the `EditText` every time you click the `button`.

The error is double: you are using `findViewById(increment)` where, in your code, increment is an `int` variable whose value is actually `0`. You have to use (as you did for the button)

```
findViewById(R.id.increment);
```

Going on:

```
                increment = Integer.parseInt(et.getText().toString());
                dialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
                dialog.setCancelable(true);
                dialog.setMessage("Loading...");
                dialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
                dialog.setProgress(0);
                EditText max = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.maximum);
                int maximum = Integer.parseInt(max.getText().toString());
```

Here the error is `xml` side: since you are assuming that `max.getText().toString()` is an `Integer`, add `inputType` to your `xml` with `number` value.

```
                dialog.setMax(maximum);
                dialog.show();
                Thread background = new Thread(new Runnable()
                {
                    public void run()
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            while (dialog.getProgress() <= dialog.getMax())
                            {
                                Thread.sleep(500);
                                progressHandler.sendMessage(progressHandler.obtainMessage());
                            }
                        } catch (java.lang.InterruptedException e)
                        {

                        }
                    }
                });
                background.start();
            }

                Handler progressHandler = new Handler() {
                    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                        dialog.incrementProgressBy(increment);
                    }
                };

        });
        }
 }
```

Another thing is that is better to avoid naming a variable with same name of your `id`, expecially because id should be representative of the control you are pointing at (for example call it "EditTextMaxValueMainActivity", this is a limit example but it is representative).

If I can suggest you, **TheNewBoston** channel/site is the best for tutorials, it has a couple of playlist with android basics to advanced and it is simple and really explicative. Good luck!

**for other errors, we will need the logtrace**

Answer (score -1):

***The Answer for me is here:***

This line:

```
EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(increment);
```

Must be changed to:

```
EditText et = (EditText) findViewById**(R.id.increment)**;
```

And i go to design view of **activity_main.xml** and changed the inputType of **increment** EditText and **maximum** EditText to number.

And removed the decimal format from the numbers.

```
  <EditText
        android:id="@+id/increment"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="5" />
```

And here i had number with decimal, now i removed them.

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/maximum"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="100" />
```